# Angular RxJs How to set debounceTime to the FormControl of FormGroup of FormArray?

Tags: rxjs, formarray, form-control, formgroups, debouncing

**Hi All,**
I have a table, where each row is a FormGroup(a form), and the row columns is a FormControl(a data input field). All FormGroup (table rows) in a FormArray.
I have no submit button, when something changed I should save that row which changed. As we know, if the field is a text input, the .valueChange is triggering at every character type. I guess probably need to use debounceTime(500) or/and distinctUntilChanged(), to prevent triggering the change before the user stopped the typing.
One more thing, probably I need to use .merge or .combineLatest to collect the field changes of the row.
My question is, how can I set the debounce time, globally to the input FormControl of the FormGroup of the FormArray?
What need to listening, so which object valueChanges should be listening? I guess the FormArray items, the FormGroup.

I thinking on something similar, probably I will resolve this on RxJS way

const field1Observable = <Observable>rowFormGroup.get('field1').valueChanges;

const field2Observable = <Observable>rowFormGroup.get('field2').valueChanges.debounceTime(500);

const field3Observable = <Observable>rowFormGroup.get('field3').valueChanges;

const field4Observable = <Observable>rowFormGroup.get('field4').valueChanges.debounceTime(500);

const field5Observable = <Observable>rowFormGroup.get('field5').valueChanges;

const combinedRowObservable = Observable.combineLatest(
[field1Observable, field2Observable, field3Observable, field4Observable, field5Observable ]
);
combinedRowObservable.subscribe(( [ f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 ] ) => {
this._logger.info('f1 ' + f1);
this._logger.info('f2 ' + f2);
this._logger.info('f3 ' + f3);
this._logger.info('f4 ' + f4);
this._logger.info('f5 ' + f5);
});

this.combinedObservables.push(combinedRowObservable);

The observables should unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this and call the form element by id:

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// elem ref
const searchBox = document.getElementById('search');

// streams
const keyup$ = fromEvent(searchBox, 'keyup');

// wait .5s between keyups to emit current value
keyup$
  .pipe(
    map((i: any) => i.currentTarget.value),
    debounceTime(500)
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

globally is in the use so be careful adding debounce time all over the place can cause unwanted slugishness - most forms are stateful - so this is really an acceptation to the rule for your particular use case.

Comment: chris burd, thank you for your reply, but I use reactive form, and I would not add key up event listener to a lot of fields.
I should use the valueChanges of FormGroup.

Comment: it doesn't matter if you are using reactive forms or not - you can use valueChanges if you like - I was just warning you about unintended consequences - not saying you would or wouldn't.